# BigQ changing dates less than 12 days from DD/MM to MM/DD

Tags: csv, date, timestamp

How do I prevent BigQ switching the day and month format from `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` in my raw `.csv` file, to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` for dates where the `D`D is less than `13`? For some reason when running a job load (with automatic schema) it is changing the timestamp format, but only for the timestamps where `"DD" = less than 13`.

Comment: What is BigQ and his is this question related to CSV?

Comment: Google BigQuery (apologies) Data analytics is new for me.